# How to send push notification from the application using parse framework?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, push-notification, parse-platform

I found [a tutorial](https://parse.com/tutorials/ios-push-notifications) to send push notifications to all devices which my app got installed. I got succeed in sending messages from the parsing.com

But, I need to send the messages from the ios app itself.

In the site, they mentioned a code that,

```
PFQuery *pushQuery = [PFInstallation query];
[pushQuery whereKey:@"deviceType" equalTo:@"ios"];

// Send push notification to query
[PFPush sendPushMessageToQueryInBackground:pushQuery
                           withMessage:@"Hello World!"];
```

I can't get what the code is exactly. I spend a day.

Can anyone tell, how to send push notifications from ios app?(ie, clicking a button)

I have the device token of the device to which the message should be send.

It will be a great help to me.

Comment: https://www.parse.com/questions/ios-push-from-an-app-to-another Consider the security implications of what you're planning...

Comment: @Wain, could you please elaborate the thing mentioned in that link, I couldn't get that.

Comment: @Wain, The issue is not sending one app to another, it is sending notification to all the devices to which the app got installed.

Comment: Have you enabled client push?

Comment: @Wain, yes I enabled the client push to ON.

Comment: Have you checked the parse log to see if it lists any issues?

Comment: @Wain, ok I'm checking that.